# Digiscoping with iPhone 11 Pro

Tags: iphone

I'm trying to digiscope with an iPhone 11 pro and an iPhone adapter on my Swarovski spotting scope and I am having problems. When I set up the spotting scope on my target with my eye everything looks great, but when I add my iPhone with the digisocping adapter I'm unable to acquire the image I want to take a picture of and have to end up backing off the zoom on the spotting scope and adding in zoom on the iPhone. This works ok, but if I add too much it goes black. I can't tell if the problem is the iPhone is trying to focus or if it's switching the lens the phone is using to one that is blocked by the digiscoping adapter.

Is there a way to control the lens the camera uses or stop the iPhone from autofocusing? Does anyone know any good procedures for taking pictures through a spotting scope with an iPhone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will probably need an app that lets you select the lens, focus, etc. [Someone](https://www.rokslide.com/forums/threads/app-to-lock-telephoto-lens-for-iphone-11-pro-max-digiscoping.165728/) says that they've tried Pro Camera by Moment and it works for them.

Comment: That works. I was hoping for something native, but this seems like the best solution so far.